# Phonegap Media Play Permissions

Tags: cordova, permissions

I am trying to create a simple Hello World Android app and add a button that plays a sound. (play.mp3)

I've included the following permissions:

```
(in app/res/xml/config.xml)
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
</feature>


(in app/AndroidManifest.xml)
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The javascipt I use:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){

  var devicereadyp = document.getElementById("deviceReadyP");
  devicereadyp.onclick= function(){
      var src = "play.mp3";
      var media = new Media(src, 
                     function(){devicereadyp.innerHTML='succes'}, 
                     function(){devicereadyp.innerHTML='failed'},
                     function(){devicereadyp.innerHTML='other'}
                  );

  media.play();
  }

}, false);
```

But the `<button id="deviceReadyP">Play sound</button>` doesn't do anything.

This will help me a lot!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to install **device plugin** and **media plugin**

Because you are accessing the device source such as Audio player and video player so you need to install device and media plugins.

```
  cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?